# Scrolling right to left using horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/resend_scroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <include layout="@layout/partial_resend_layout"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:id="@+id/resend_invite"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_invitee_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/regular_roboto"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_invitee_contact_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/regular_roboto"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is my xml file but linearlayout match_parent width is not working both include and the layout is visible in screen! I'm scrolling the item right to left so the item at the left side should not be visible! I dont know how to do that..
This xml file is item of recyclerview. if i set the width to some value it works fine. but when screen size changes width size changes hence it shows the include partially now i'm doing this

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, holder.mWidthTextView.getHeight());
        holder.mWidthTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        holder.mResendScroll.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                holder.mResendScroll.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 10L);
```

It works but i dont think this is the correct way as this is called every time in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Simple. Do this in onCreate of your activity/fragment after creating object of HorizontalScrollView. `resend_scroll.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);`

Comment: i'll edit my question

Comment: Plz, Be clear on what you are asking and present your code and issue completely.

Comment: For Updated Question, AFAIK That's the only way for your design implementation. May be you can "Give negative margin left to your parent LinearLayout inside HSV"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to  first LinearLayout width "match_parent".

From code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">`
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">`
```

Comment: Thank you, well i need to swipe Right to left hence first linearlayout should not be visible.

Comment: Sorry can't understand what you need .Please clear then may be can i help